# Oauth for Google API example using Python / Django

Tags: python, django, oauth, google-api

I am trying to get Oauth working with the Google API using Python. I have tried different oauth libraries such as [oauth](http://github.com/leah/python-oauth/), [oauth2](http://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2) and [djanog-oauth](http://code.welldev.org/django-oauth/wiki/Home) but I cannot get it to work (including the provided examples).

For debugging Oauth I use Google's [Oauth Playground](http://googlecodesamples.com/oauth_playground/) and I have studied the [API](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref.html) and the [Oauth documentation](http://oauth.net/core/1.0/)

With some libraries I am struggling with getting a right signature, with other libraries I am struggling with converting the request token to an authorized token. What would really help me if someone can show me a working example for the Google API using one of the above-mentioned libraries.

EDIT: My initial question did not lead to any answers so I have added my code. There are two possible causes of this code not working:
1) Google does not authorize my request token, but not quite sure how to detect this
2) THe signature for the access token is invalid but then I would like to know which oauth parameters Google is expecting as I am able to generate a proper signature in the first phase.

This is written using oauth2.py and for Django hence the HttpResponseRedirect.

```
REQUEST_TOKEN_URL = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken'
AUTHORIZATION_URL = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken'
ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken'

CALLBACK = 'http://localhost:8000/mappr/mappr/oauth/' #will become real server when deployed

OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY = 'anonymous'
OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET = 'anonymous'

signature_method = oauth.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1()
consumer = oauth.Consumer(key=OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, secret=OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET)
client = oauth.Client(consumer)

request_token = oauth.Token('','') #hackish way to be able to access the token in different functions, I know this is bad, but I just want it to get working in the first place :)

def authorize(request):
    if request.GET == {}:
        tokens = OAuthGetRequestToken()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(AUTHORIZATION_URL + '?' + tokens)
    elif request.GET['oauth_verifier'] != '':
        oauth_token = request.GET['oauth_token']
        oauth_verifier = request.GET['oauth_verifier']
        OAuthAuthorizeToken(oauth_token)
        OAuthGetAccessToken(oauth_token, oauth_verifier)
        #I need to add a Django return object but I am still debugging other phases.

def OAuthGetRequestToken():
    print '*** OUTPUT OAuthGetRequestToken ***'
    params = {
    'oauth_consumer_key': OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, 
    'oauth_nonce':  oauth.generate_nonce(),
    'oauth_signature_method': 'HMAC-SHA1',
    'oauth_timestamp': int(time.time()), #The timestamp should be expressed in number of seconds after January 1, 1970 00:00:00 GMT.
    'scope': 'https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/',
    'oauth_callback': CALLBACK,
    'oauth_version': '1.0'
    }

    # Sign the request.
    req = oauth.Request(method="GET", url=REQUEST_TOKEN_URL, parameters=params)
    req.sign_request(signature_method, consumer, None)

    tokens =client.request(req.to_url())[1]
    params = ConvertURLParamstoDictionary(tokens)
    request_token.key  = params['oauth_token']
    request_token.secret =  params['oauth_token_secret']
    return tokens

def OAuthAuthorizeToken(oauth_token):
    print '*** OUTPUT OAuthAuthorizeToken ***'
    params ={
    'oauth_token' :oauth_token,
    'hd': 'default'
    }
    req = oauth.Request(method="GET", url=AUTHORIZATION_URL, parameters=params)
    req.sign_request(signature_method, consumer, request_token)
    response =client.request(req.to_url())
    print response #for debugging purposes

def OAuthGetAccessToken(oauth_token, oauth_verifier):
    print '*** OUTPUT OAuthGetAccessToken ***'
    params = {
    'oauth_consumer_key':  OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY,
    'oauth_token': oauth_token,
    'oauth_verifier': oauth_verifier,
    'oauth_token_secret': request_token.secret,
    'oauth_signature_method': 'HMAC-SHA1',
    'oauth_timestamp': int(time.time()),
    'oauth_nonce': oauth.generate_nonce(),
    'oauth_version': '1.0',    
    }

    req = oauth.Request(method="GET", url=ACCESS_TOKEN_URL, parameters=params)
    req.sign_request(signature_method, consumer, request_token)

    response =client.request(req.to_url())
    print response
    return req

def ConvertURLParamstoDictionary(tokens):
    params = {}
    tokens = tokens.split('&')
    for token in tokens:
        token = token.split('=')
        params[token[0]] = token[1]

    return params
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have OAuth working in a python App Engine app:

http://github.com/sje397/Chess

The app is running at:

http://your-move.appspot.com

Answer (score 5):

This work for me.

```
def login(request):
     consumer_key    =   'blabla'
     consumer_secret =   'blabla'
     callback = request.GET['callback']
     request_token_url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken'
     authorize_url =     'https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize'
     access_token_url =  'https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken'
     consumer = oauth.Consumer(consumer_key, consumer_secret)

     if ('oauth_verifier' not in request.GET):
       client = oauth.Client(consumer)
       body = 'oauth_callback=http://shofin.com/login?callback='+callback+"&placeId="+request.GET[placeId]
       resp,content = client.request(request_token_url,"POST",headers={'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},body=body)
       request_token = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(content))
       loginUrl = authorize_url+"?oauth_token="+request_token['oauth_token']
       cache.set(request_token['oauth_token'],request_token['oauth_token_secret'])
       return HttpResponseRedirect(loginUrl)

     elif request.GET['oauth_verifier']:
       token = oauth.Token(request.GET['oauth_token'],cache.get(request.GET['oauth_token']))
       token.set_verifier(request.GET['oauth_verifier'])
       client = oauth.Client(consumer, token)
       resp,content = client.request(access_token_url,"POST",{})
       access_token = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(content))
       token = oauth.Token(key=access_token['oauth_token'], secret=access_token['oauth_token_secret'])

       client = oauth.Client(consumer, token)
       resp,json = client.request("http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json")
       return render_to_response(callback,{'placeId':request.GET['placeId'],'userId':userId,'folkId':folkId)
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the official gdata python api ?
It ships with an oauth client and hides the complexity of oauth calls.
http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/

Answer (score 2):

This may be the answer.

When calling OAuthGetRequestToken you sign the base_string with your consumer_secret followed by an & (ampersand)

When calling OAuthGetAccessToken you sign the base_string with your consumer_secret followed by an & (ampersand) followed by token_secret.

You would sign the base_string using (consumer_secret + "&") for OAuthGetRequestToken and 
you would sign the base_string using (consumer_secret + "&" + token_secret) for OAuthGetAccessToken

> http://hueniverse.com/2008/10/beginners-guide-to-oauth-part-iii-security-architecture/
>   In the PLAINTEXT and HMAC-SHA1 methods, the shared secret is the combination of the Consumer Secret and Token Secret.

Answer (score 2):

Tornado has working code for Google oauth. Check it out here. [google auth](http://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/auth.py#L588). I 've used it and worked pretty well out of the box. All you need to do is pluck out the class and carefully put it into a django view.

PS: Tornado makes use of async module for the user to return. Since you are using django you need to rely on some get variable to identify that a user has just granted access to your application.

Comment: this examples uses Google+ API Backend Code only or it's a mixture or Both Client and Backend?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC Google oauth is not quite following the standard, you *have* to specify what service you're requesting for (look at the examples provided in the google docs) in the request as an additional parameter, or it won't work.